# Testing the method that has stream () and filter ()

Tags: java, spring, testing

For the method

```
    public List<OtherTitle> getTitles(
        @Min(1) final Long id
) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    log.info("Called with id {}", id);

    return this.findMovie(id).getOtherTitles()
            .stream()
            .filter(title -> title.getStatus() == DataStatus.ACCEPTED)
            .map(ServiceUtils::toOtherTitleDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I wrote a test

```
    @Test
public void canGetMovieTitles() throws ResourceException {
    final Long id = new Random().nextLong();
    final MovieEntity entity = Mockito.mock(MovieEntity.class);
    Mockito.when(entity.getOtherTitles()).thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList());
    Mockito
            .when(this.movieRepository.findByIdAndStatus(id, DataStatus.ACCEPTED))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(entity));
    Assert.assertTrue(this.service.getTitles(id).isEmpty());
}
```

With the help of the `Jacoco` tool, I wanted to check the scope of the tests. It turns out that the `getTitles()` method is 100% tested, but lambda with this method has a range of 0% https://zapodaj.net/303603912f57f.png.html. In the preview https://zapodaj.net/d68d7252b1d17.png.html, the filter () is highlighted on the yellow.

How do you test this `filter()` method with `stream()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your implementation for DataStatus looks like this:

```
public enum DataStatus {
    ACCEPTED,
    REJECTED;
}
```

Add another test that looks something like this

```
@Test
public void canGetMovieTitles() throws ResourceException {
    List<OtherTitle> othertitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    OtherTitle ot = new OtherTitle();
    ot.setTitle(DataStatus.ACCEPTED);
    othertitleList.add(ot); 
    ot = new OtherTitle();
    ot.setTitle(DataStatus.REJECTED);
    othertitleList.add(ot);

    final Long id = new Random().nextLong();
    final MovieEntity entity = Mockito.mock(MovieEntity.class);
    Mockito.when(entity.getOtherTitles()).thenReturn(othertitleList);
    Mockito.when(this.movieRepository.findByIdAndStatus(id, DataStatus.ACCEPTED)).thenReturn(Optional.of(entity));
    Assert.assertEquals(1, this.service.getTitles(id).size());
}
```

Problem is that the filter will never need to filter anything if the list is empty. So we add two other titles, one that should be accepted by the filter and one that should be rejected by the filter. This should give us 100% coverage on the filter.